# CouchDB - database does not exist

Tags: couchdb

I create a database in couchDB this way:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/couch-peruser.html

The problem: when I create a user in couch I immediately load data to the database. (I assume the database exists). Unfortunately there is no the database, the database is created some time later.
Do you have any idea how to create the user and be certain the database exists?

The situation:                                                                           CREATE_USER <---- I create user in this line and operation is fine
LOAD_DATABASE <---- I try to load to database with this name userdb-{hex encoded username} but not exist.

A few miliseconds later the database is created but too late. When I put Thread.sleep(2000) between CREATE_USER and LOAD_DATABASE the code works fine but I do not want to use thread.sleep.

Comment: Did you truly enable `[couch_peruser]` configuration? Did you note that the created database for the user, would have a name in the format: `userdb-{hex encoded username}`

Comment: Having same issue here. Database is created, but some time after the user is added, and I haven't yet figured out how to add a document to the new userdb as soon as it's created.